# Selenium/Python - Finding Dynamically Created Fields

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Newbie here... 2 days into learning this.

In a learning management system, there is an element (a plus mark icon) to click which adds a form field upon each click.  The goal is to click the icon, which generates a new field, and then put text into the new field.  This field does NOT exist when the page loads... it's added dynamically based on the clicking of the icon.

When I try to use "driver.find_element_by_*" (have tried ID, Name and xpath), I get an error that it can't be found.  I'm assuming it's because it wasn't there when the page loaded.  Any way to resolve this?

By the way, I've been successful in scripting the login process and navigating through the site to get to this point. So, I have actually learned how to find other elements that are static.

Let me know if I need to provide more info or a better description.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to have patience and let something catch up...

I added:

*import time*

and then:

*time.sleep(3)*

after the click on the icon to add the field.  It's working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.sleep(3) but that would force you to wait for the entire 3 seconds before using that element. In Selenium we use webdriver waits that polls the DOM to allow us to immediately use that element as quick as possible when it is useable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,""))).click()
```

Comment: Excellent!  I'll incorporate that method instead! Thanks